# missing template arguments before '*' token

Tags: c++

having difficulty getting the main method to compile.
The error is on line 10:

```
missing template argument before * token.
myChain was not  declared  in this scoop
expected type-specifier before 'chain'
expected ';' before 'chain'
```

Below is the code where the error occurs.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "chain.h"
#include "IOcode.h"
#include "chainNode.h"

using namespace std;

int main (){

    chain *myChain=new chain(10);
    userInputOutput(myChain, "chain");
}
```

chainNode.h dependency

```
#ifndef chainNode_
#define chainNode_

template <class T>
struct chainNode 
{
   // data members
   T element;
   chainNode<T> *next;

   // methods
   chainNode() {}
   chainNode(const T& element)
      {this->element = element;}
   chainNode(const T& element, chainNode<T>* next)
      {this->element = element;
       this->next = next;}
};

#endif
```

chain.h dependency
class definition for chain.

```
#ifndef chain_
#define chain_

#include<iostream>
#include<sstream>
#include<string>
#include "linearList.h"
#include "chainNode.h"
#include "myExceptions.h"

class linkedDigraph;
template <class T> class linkedWDigraph;

template<class T>
class chain: public linearList
{
   friend class linkedDigraph;
   friend class linkedWDigraph<int>;
   friend class linkedWDigraph<float>;
   friend class linkedWDigraph<double>;
   public:
      // constructor, copy constructor and destructor
      chain(int initialCapacity = 10);
      chain(const chain<T>&);
      ~chain();

      // ADT methods
      bool empty() const {return listSize == 0;}
      int size() const {return listSize;}
      T& get(int theIndex) const;
      int indexOf(const T& theElement) const;
      void erase(int theIndex);
      void insert(int theIndex, const T& theElement);
      void output(ostream& out) const;

   protected:
      void checkIndex(int theIndex) const;
            // throw illegalIndex if theIndex invalid
      chainNode<T>* firstNode;  // pointer to first node in chain
      int listSize;             // number of elements in list
};
```

IOcode.h dependency

```
#include <iostream>
#include "linearList.h"

using namespace std;

void userInputOutput (linearList* l, string dataStructure);
```

Answer (score 8):

This class is templated, meaning you have to specify a type to fill in for the template, so you would say

```
chain<string> *myChain=new chain<string>(10);
```

instead of

```
chain *myChain=new chain(10);
```

if you wanted to use this chain for strings, for example.